# what does find_element_by_tag_name(RowOfAtable) returns ? in Python

Tags: python, html

I am trying to get the columns of the first row of the html table, this is the html code:

```
<table id="switches-table" class="display initialized dataTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" aria-describedby="switches-table_info">
<thead>
<tr role="row" class="row_selected">
<th class="ui-state-default center" data-column-index="0" role="columnheader" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 1%;" aria-label="">
<th class="center ui-state-default" data-column-index="1" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="switches-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column ascending">
<th class="center ui-state-default" data-column-index="2" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="switches-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="IP: activate to sort column descending" aria-sort="ascending">
<th class="center ui-state-default" data-column-index="3" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="switches-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Software Version: activate to sort column ascending">
<th class="center ui-state-default" data-column-index="4" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="switches-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Health: activate to sort column ascending">
</tr>
</thead>
```

i want to reach the attribute (aria-label)
i first got the head of the table with tag , then row with tag  then columns of that first row by  , it must return an array of the elements, is that correct ? 
so i tried to find its length and loop through it, then my next step is to find the attribute , but the main problem now is :
when i use `find_element_by_tag_name("th)` , i cant figure out what type is it or what does it return ?
this is my code so far

```
   try:
      thead = table.find_element_by_tag_name("thead")
      firstRow = thead.find_element_by_tag_name("tr")
      colOfFirstRow = firstRow.find_element_by_tag_name("th")

      for i in range (0,colOfFirstRow.__len__()-1):  
          wanted = colOfFirstRow.find_elements_by_class_name("center ui-state-default")
          print colOfFirstRow.attribute["aria-lable"].split()[0]

      if th.attribute["aria-lable"].split()[0].__eq__(columnName): //columnName is a paramenter
            flag = 1
            return True
      if flag == 0:
            return False
    except:
        print "fail"
```

Comment: Are you using selenium or BeautifulSoup?

Comment: selenium @shaktimaan

Comment: can you also post the error log with this code snippet?

Comment: do a `type(colOfFirstRow)` to see the type

Comment: HI :) , thanks @sk11 , there is no errors actually, am just not able to find the right function that gives me the result i want, and in python on eclips , it does nt really gives me hints or errors or ..
but i'll try type(), i made some progress, i got stuck into other issues now, 
when i run the unitTest, and i click on tables and stuff, i should be removing elements from the table, but when i print the content of the table , they are not deleted, even i make it wait or sth.
my friend told me, i should write it as a code, and delete it from table, i dont get that point very much, any hints ?

Comment: Sorry Rymi but I am unable to understand your reply ! Please update the question with your problem and the expected outcome.